# Unamos [intellij] e [intellij-idea]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Estas etiquetas bien podrían ser una sola, pues ambas se refieren al IDE Intellij IDEA de Jet Brains:

- [intellij](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij), con 61 preguntas
- [intellij-idea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea), con 30

Yo optaría por poner como principal [intellij-idea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hecho. He dejado como principal [intellij-idea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea)